# Mysql Error 1192 while importing from mysqldump backup

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

We are trying to clone Mysql Cluster (ClusterDB) database on same instance by taking backup with Mysqldump and then restoring it with mysql as following:

```
mysqldump -u masterdb1 -p --single-transaction db_master_1 > db_master_1_bk.sql
mysql -u testdev -p db_testdev_1 < db_master_1_bk.sql
```

However while restoring it throws an error:

> ERROR 1192 (HY000) at line 112: Can't execute the given command
>   because you have active locked tables or an active transaction

Any Help..? Thanks.

Comment: This may help:  http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=40346   Check your version of mysql.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, we are running much later release our version is "mysql-5.5.30 ndb-7.2.12"

Comment: while restoring --add-locks=0, did solve our issue, many thanks for your help